# How to use Dir.mktmpdir with a block in a hook with rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, hook, block

I want to create a tmpdir in a `before`-each hook and use its path in an rspec example. I want to use the block form of `Dir.mktmpdir` so the dir is removed at the end of the example.

**Problems:**

- I can't let the block exit in the `before` hook, or the dir is removed before my example can run.
- I can't wrap a block around my example. I tried using an `around`
  hook, but that doesn't share instance variables with examples (the
  [doc](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/dir/hooks/around-hooks) confirms this behavior).

Currently I'm using continuations (Fibers would be better if I were on 1.9) to jump out of the block, then jump back in so `mktmpdir` can clean up.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this, without moving `mktmpdir` inside each example? It's true that I can remove the dir in the `after`-hook, but I'm also looking for a general solution to this type of problem - I don't always know what cleanup code is supposed to run when the block exits.

FYI, my continuation code, encapsulated into a class:

```
class SuspendableBlock
  def initialize
  end

  def run(&block)
    raise LocalJumpError unless block_given?
    callcc {|@run_cc|
      yield
      @resume_cc.call if @resume_cc
    }
    nil
  end

  # saves the suspend point & causes run to return immediately
  def suspend
    raise "run must be called first" unless @run_cc
    callcc {|@suspend_cc|
      @run_cc.call(@suspend_cc)
    }
    nil
  end

  # jumps back to after the suspend point to finish the block.
  # after the block exits, return immediately from resume.
  def resume
    raise "suspend must be called first" unless @suspend_cc
    callcc {|@resume_cc|
      @suspend_cc.call(@resume_cc)
    }
    nil
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
before :each do
  @sb = SuspendableBlock.new
  @sb.run do
    Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
      @tmpdir_path = Pathname.new(dir)
      @sb.suspend
    end
  end
end

after :each do
  @sb.resume
end

it "should use a tmp dir" do
  p @tmpdir_path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I read (never tested it) continuations are really inefficient.

While I cannot help you on continuations you could use Thread to mimic Fibers: https://github.com/tmm1/fiber18.

One library which already does that is em-spec (https://github.com/tmm1/em-spec), with it each test is ran in a fiber you may be able to modify it to match your needs.